# Error finding bean when using Watson spring-boot-starter

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-watson

I followed the steps in https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/spring-boot-starter to try an call the Watson Conversation(Assistant) service in a Spring boot application, however I am getting this error:

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field service in application.ConverseApiBinding required a bean of
>   type 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.conversation.v1.Conversation'
>   that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.conversation.v1.Conversation' in your
>   configuration.

Is there thing else I need to do apart from adding dependencies (I used maven) and

```
@Autowired
protected Conversation service;
```

The service url and credentials are provided in the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have something in your application properties file to signal that the conversation bean should be created.  Normally this would be the service credentials.

In the case where the service credentials come from `VCAP_SERVICES`, you can simply specify

`watson.conversation.enabled=true`

in your application properties file.  That should trigger the creation of the bean.